# Subversion with LDAP authentication

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ldap

I'm facing issues with configuring SVN with LDAP.

- SVN Version: 1.6.6
- Apache version: 2.2
- I am using the TortoiseSVN client to access the repository.

I've copied the "mod_authz_svn.so" and "mod_dav_svn.so" from SVN to the modules directory of the Apache installation. Apache starts normally without any trouble.

Below is my configuration file.

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath d:/repos
    SVNListParentPath On
    AuthzSVNAccessFile D:/repos/access.txt
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName “ou.org”
    #AuthLDAPBindDN “CN=TROPHY,CN=Users,DC=vw,DC=vwg”
    AuthLDAPBindDN "DOMAIN\TROPHY"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword “SYPERB”

    AuthLDAPURL ldap://OU.ORG:389/CN=Users,DC=OU,DC=ORG?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=Users)

    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Error:200 OK

If I replace the "/svn" from the location path, I don't see the above error, but I was unable to authenticate to the server. I notice that the  login prompt pops up every time I give the credentials.

I'm using the below link to access the repository from TortoiseSVN.

http://server.ou.org/repos/make/

Comment: This might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841275/use-ldap-for-svn-user-authentication

Comment: why is this question tagged xbox360?

Comment: I know this sounds crazy, but for your location, have you tried `/svn/`? The trailing slash has worked for me in the past (on windows only, though) And shouldn't your access path be http://server.ou.org/svn/make/ ?

Answer (score -2):

Check out [Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/). It might help.